# Driver for Epson L360 scanner

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

Can't connect to the scanner of Epson L360 with the standard epson linux deb scanner driver (http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html.). Are more advanced drivers available or other ways to connect to the scanner?

Comment: What are the errors exactly? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/930700/edit) your question with the relevant error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong place to get the drivers. That bundle does not have a required plugin.

Get the drivers [HERE](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Enter the model name and you will get the correct bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You may download the **Epson Scan 2** for Linux here:

https://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php

For 64-bit Ubuntu this is the direct download as of 2022:

https://download2.ebz.epson.net/epsonscan2/common/deb/x64/epsonscan2-bundle-6.7.0.0.x86_64.deb.tar.gz

It is a tarfile and you will need to extract it. There is an `install.sh` file that you can run, e.g.

```
$ sh install.sh
```

or

```
$ ./install.sh
```

Or what I did is just to

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

for the two `deb` files in the decompressed folders.